# Using std::cout in Qt Gui

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, cout

I have an application that when run through terminal, the user has the option between command-line mode or GUI mode.

There doesn't seem to be any output to the console at all when using `std::cout`. `std::cout` statements don't work in the main event loop.

I have added `CONFIG += console` to my `.pro` file.

For now, I have been using `QTextStream()` which works fine:

`QTextStream(cout) << "Hello World" << std::endl;`

My question is:

Why can I not use `std::cout`? Does this have something to do with `Qt` affecting input and output streams? I couldn't find any documentation in Qt's docs on this.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;  //This is being outputted.

    //if(argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1],"-win")){
    if(true){ //Just for this example's sake
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;   //This is not being ouputted. 
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()  << "Console Mode.\n";
        std::cout << "Console Mode.\n";

        //Do stuff
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Qt issue, but how `std::cout` works. You seem to blow up your `std::cout` in here:

```
std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
```

Your issue can be reproduced even with a simple program like this:

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int /*argc*/, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello stdout!" << std::endl;
    if (std::cout.bad())
        std::cerr << "I/O error while reading\n";
    return 0;
}
```

#### Build and Run

```
Success: qmake && make && ./main foo
Failure: qmake && make && ./main
```

In your case `argv[1]` is nil and so this makes `std::cout` not to print anything more. I would suggest to either pass an argument all the time and/or check against argc with some help usage print. The best would be to use the builtin command line parser in QtCore these days.

You could ask why? Because it is undefined behavior. You can read the details from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb);
```

> After constructing and checking the sentry object, checks if sb is a null pointer. If it is, executes setstate(badbit) and exits.

If you happen to have an issue with the IDE itself, for instance QtCreator, then follow these steps in case of QtCreator:

```
Projects -> Select a kit -> Run tab -> Run section -> Arguments
```

Comment: I derpped, was running the program from Qt Creator the whole time. I fixed the problem with your help.

Answer (score 1):

Works OK for me:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = untitled
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

EDIT:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QDebug>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;  // <--- THE PROBLEM IS HERE...IF YOU TRY A SIMPLE STRING IT WORKS FINE SO THE PROBLEM IS argv[1] IS AN EMPTY STRING

    //if(argc == 2 && !strcmp(argv[1],"-win")){
    if(true){
        //Just for this example's sake
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;   //This is not being ouputted.

        return a.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()  << "Console Mode.\n";
        std::cout << "Console Mode.\n";

        //Do stuff
    } }
```

Comment: The OP said in the main event loop, but you call your print before the event loop.

Comment: You were screwing the arguments, it wasn't a Qt problem...I just saw the source code of the updated version of the question...

Comment: I was not screwing anything lol. I am not the OP. ;-) Moreover, you still do not seem to get the problem. The problem is _not_ that it is an empty string. The problem is that it is a _nil_ string.

Comment: What do you mean by OP?